# How can I reduce cooldown time after a failed restart vote in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

We have a private dedicated CS:GO server, but sometimes when a player casts a restart or change map vote early and it fails, we have a huge cooldown time until we can ask for another restart (it is, I think, around 2xx seconds).

Can we add some configuration to reduce this amount?

Note: The admin is one of us, but he is not available all the time to do a force-restart by using the command `rcon mp_restartgame`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sv_vote_creation_time "60"`

- cooldown of an individual player to cast another vote

`sv_vote_failure_timer "60"`

- cooldown of a failed vote

The values are in seconds. So in my example the cooldown would be one minute in both cases.